# JSTL division is automatically rounded to 1 or 0

Tags: java, spring-mvc, jstl, division

I found a lot of questions asking about how to round a number in JSTL. My question is the opposite. Somehow when I calculate wins / total to get the percentage of wins I always get either 0 or 1. The pattern is consistent: If wins >= losses, the result is 1, otherwise zero. So it seems like there's a Math.round being performed here somewhere. But I have no idea where it comes from.

I have been trying to reproduce this error, but whenever I try to reproduce it I actually get the value that I am expecting (a value **between** 0 and 1). This makes me think that the problem is because I am performing a SQL query, and adding the list result to the model (I'm using Spring MVC) although I am not sure why that would be the problem.

Spring MVC controller code:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/player/{player}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String player(@PathVariable String player, Model model) {
    String query = "SELECT v2.player, SUM(IF(v1.result >= 26, 1, 0)) `playerWins`, " +
            "SUM(IF(v2.result >= 26, 1, 0)) `oppWins` FROM mines_playing AS v1 " +
            "JOIN mines_playing AS v2 ON (v1.gameid = v2.gameid) AND (v1.playerpos != v2.playerpos) " +
            "JOIN mines AS v3 ON (v1.gameid = v3.gameid) AND v3.finished = 1 " +
            "WHERE v1.player = ? AND v3.finished = 1 " +
            "GROUP BY v2.player " +
            "ORDER BY playerWins DESC";

    Session sess = sessionFactory.openSession();
    SQLQuery q = sess.createSQLQuery(query);
    q.setString(0, player);
    q.setResultTransformer(Transformers.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP);

    List<?> list = q.list();
    model.addAttribute("size", list.size());
    model.addAttribute("winList", list);
    model.addAttribute("player", player);

    sess.disconnect();
    return "player/playerstats";
}
```

JSTL code:

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@ page session="false" %>
(...)

<c:forEach items="${winList}" var="element">
    <c:set var="lost" value="${element['oppWins']}" />
    <c:set var="wins" value="${element['playerWins']}" />

    <c:set var="total" value="${wins + lost}" />
    <c:if test="${total > 0}">
    <tr>
        <td><a href="<c:url value="vs/${element['player']}" />"><c:out value="${element['player']}">Null</c:out></a></td>
        <td>${total}</td>
        <td>${wins}</td>
        <td>${lost}</td>
        <td>${wins / total}</td>
    </tr>
    </c:if>
</c:forEach>
```

What am I doing wrong? Why is the value of wins / total automatically rounded?

Comment: have you tried using a fmt tag? <fmt:formatNumber type="number" 
            maxFractionDigits="3" value="${wins / total}" />

Comment: @orangegoat I have tried it, but perhaps I did it wrong or it did not work. It just resulted in `1.00` or `0.00`. Your code there did not work either.

Comment: if you just have ${5/3} does it print out as 1.6666666666666667

Comment: @orangegoat Yes. ${5/3} becomes 1.6666666666666667

Comment: I'd love to know why I got a downvote on the question. I hope the answer is not `because it's too difficult to answer`.

Comment: Maybe this will work <c:out value="${wins / total}"/>

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you using a "dividable" datatype?

Try parsing it to number. Like so:

```
<c:set var="wins" ><fmt:parseNumber type="number" value="${element['playerWins']}" /></c:set>
<c:set var="lost" ><fmt:parseNumber type="number" value="${element['oppWins']}" /></c:set>
```

Comment: I have no idea what datatype it was before, but this works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You can't tell from the code, but I would imagine it's because wins and total are integers. Integer division results in an integer.

Comment: I have been trying to perform `1.0 * wins / total` as well. Same result. Also, integer division usually **always rounds down**

Comment: You should try `wins / (total * 1.0)` to cast the actual division expression to float/double. The one you have still has an integer division expression.

Comment: Tried that now. Same result :/

Comment: `(wins / total) * 1.1 / 1.1` works for me. `(wins / total) * (1.1 / 1.1)` does not work, neither `(wins / total) * 1.0 / 1.0`